# Access 2003 - VBA/query Error message

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to get something done within access lately and having a problem that I can't quiet figure.

I got this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub cboLocation_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboServer.RowSource = " SELECT tbl2Server.ServerID, tbl2Server.ServerName FROM tbl2Server " & _
        " WHERE LocationName = " & Nz(Me.cboLocation) & _
        " ORDER BY ServerName"
    Me.cboServer = Null

    EnableControls
    FilterInterfacesList

End Sub

Private Sub cboServer_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboInterface.RowSource = " SELECT tbl2Vlan.VlanID, tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName FROM tbl2Vlan " & _
        " WHERE LocationName = " & Nz(Me.cboLocation) & _
        " ORDER BY InterfaceName"
    Me.cboInterface = Null

    EnableControls
    FilterInterfacesList

End Sub

Private Sub cboInterface_AfterUpdate()
    EnableControls
    FilterInterfacesList

End Sub

Private Sub FilterInterfacesList()
    Dim strInterface As String

    strInterface = "SELECT qryServerInterfaces.LocationName, qryServerInterfaces.ServerName, qryServerInterfaces.InterfaceName, qryServerInterfaces.VlanName, qryServerInterfaces.IPAddress, qryServerInterfaces.DefaultGatewayAddress FROM qryServerooInterfaces"

    If Not IsNull(Me.cboInterface) Then
        strInterface = strInterface & " WHERE InterfaceName = " & Me.cboInterface
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboServer) Then
        strInterface = strInterface & " WHERE ServerName = " & Me.cboServer
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.cboLocation) Then
        strInterface = strInterface & " WHERE LocationName = " & Me.cboLocation
    End If

    strInterface = strInterface & " ORDER BY qryServerInterfaces.LocationName;"

    Me.lstInterfaces.RowSource = strInterface

    Me.lstInterfaces.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub EnableControls()

    If IsNull(Me.cboLocation) Then
        Me.cboServer = Null
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.cboServer) Then
        Me.cboInterface = Null
    End If

    Me.cboServer.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboLocation))
    Me.cboInterface.Enabled = (Not IsNull(Me.cboServer))

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    EnableControls

End Sub
```

and a query that looks like this:
[My query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgMZW.png)

Now. my problem that if i'll Criteria under "thing" Or Like "thing" Is Null my query will show information. if i'm not putting everything under "null" my form (picture below) won't show me anything within his list.

Now, when I do "null" my criteria - I'm getting wierd message which tells me I'm having a failure or something (picture below).

Does anyone knows what is up? thanks in advance! i'm stuck with it for 2 weeks already :'(

[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJgp.png)

Thanks in advance for any possible help!

SQL Code

```
SELECT      tbl1Location.LocationName, 
            tbl2Server.ServerName, 
            tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName, 
            tbl2Vlan.VlanName, 
            tbl3IP.IPAddress, 
            tbl2Vlan.DefaultGatewayAddress
FROM        ((tbl1Location INNER JOIN tbl2Server ON tbl1Location.LocationID = tbl2Server.LocationName) 
                           INNER JOIN tbl2Vlan ON tbl1Location.LocationID = tbl2Vlan.LocationName) 
                           INNER JOIN tbl3IP ON (tbl2Server.ServerID = tbl3IP.ServerName) 
                                            AND (tbl2Vlan.VlanID = tbl3IP.InterfaceName)
WHERE       (
             ((tbl1Location.LocationName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) AND 
             ((tbl2Server.ServerName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) AND 
             ((tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface])
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl2Server.ServerName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) AND 
             ((tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) AND 
             ((([tbl1Location].[LocationName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl1Location.LocationName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) AND 
             ((tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) AND 
             ((([tbl2Server].[ServerName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl2Vlan.InterfaceName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) AND 
             ((([tbl1Location].[LocationName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) Is Null) AND 
             ((([tbl2Server].[ServerName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl1Location.LocationName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) AND 
             ((tbl2Server.ServerName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) AND 
             ((([tbl2Vlan].[InterfaceName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl2Server.ServerName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) AND 
             ((([tbl1Location].[LocationName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) Is Null) AND 
             ((([tbl2Vlan].[InterfaceName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((tbl1Location.LocationName)=[Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) AND 
             ((([tbl2Server].[ServerName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) Is Null) AND 
             ((([tbl2Vlan].[InterfaceName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) Is Null)
            ) OR 
            (
             ((([tbl1Location].[LocationName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboLocation]) Is Null) AND 
             ((([tbl2Server].[ServerName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboServer]) Is Null) AND 
             ((([tbl2Vlan].[InterfaceName]) Like [Forms]![frmInterfaces]![cboInterface]) Is Null)
            )
```

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1cvyN.png - The error message

Comment: That is a weird query - not a weird error message. If you can View SQL and copy/paste is a text in your question wrapped by {} code tags, it would be easier to see. I think there's probably a way to eliminate some of those joins - they almost look circular. You might have build some subqueries - then join them in this query

Comment: i've added it, went to the query and just copy pasted all of the visible code i've seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem:

I've "fixed" it by deleting my old query and debug each and every change i've made to the new one.

also i've learned that if I want any value to be inside any list the query should contain the value, the proper key and that's about it. you can manage what your list will show you afterwards within the vba code by:

Me.mylist.RawSource = 'SELECT firstValue.myQuery , secondValue.myQuery , thirdValue.myQuery FROM myQuery'

The query need to hold both your data values and your IDs.